# does ATtiny85 handles the size of the libraries mentioned below `<MD_Parola.h>` and `<MD_MAX72xx.h>`

Tags: attiny85

The ATtiny85 microcontroller has very limited resources, including program memory (flash) and RAM. It has 8KB of flash memory and only 512 bytes of RAM.

does ATtiny85 handles the size of the libraries  mentioned below
`<MD_Parola.h>` and `<MD_MAX72xx.h>`

what microcontroller would you recommend?

https://www.arduinolibraries.info/libraries/md_max72-xx

https://reference.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/md_parola/

Comment: Can you at least please give a link to the libraries you mention? Are you expecting us to Google for where they are and then read all the documentation for them? Asking for recommendations is a bit broad. It depends. What else are you trying to do? What are your price constraints? A quick Google search indicates the libraries do not mention what processor they target, so it is hard to answer. Just as a guess (and this is a guess) they probably are for the larger processors like the Atmega328P.

Comment: Thank you @NickGammon for the quick response. Please  find the docs reference of the library and I will check Atmega328P
https://reference.arduino.cc/reference/en/libraries/md_parola/
https://www.arduinolibraries.info/libraries/md_max72-xx

Answer (score 3):

It is very simple to test.

1. [Install the ATTinyCore](https://github.com/SpenceKonde/ATTinyCore/blob/v2.0.0-devThis-is-the-head-submit-PRs-against-this/Installation.md#boards-manager-installation) in IDE
2. Install the MD_Parola library in Library Manager. It will install the MD_MAX72xx library too
3. Go to IDE Examples menu, search for the MD_Parola library examples and select the Parola_HelloWorld example
4. select the ATTiny85 in the Tools menu
5. hit Verify

output:

```
avr/bin/ld: region `text' overflowed by 11820 bytes
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
exit status 1
Error compiling for board ATtiny45/85 (Optiboot)
```

which means it will not fit.

If you select Arduino Uno in the Tools menu and Verify you get:

```
Sketch uses 20692 bytes (64%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32256 bytes.
Global variables use 288 bytes (14%) of dynamic memory, leaving 1760 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.
```

Comment: thank you @Juraj !!!I will consider Atmega328P